# Does it ever make sense to use curved shadows on flat objects?

Tags: website-design, web, aesthetics, shape

What's the rationale behind styling flat/straight boxes to cast curved shadows on flat/straight surfaces?

[image]

<sup>Image credit: http://cjwainwright.co.uk/webdev/liftedcorners/</sup>

Sure it makes the object stand out, but this shadow is physically impossible. The paper is straight (no curled up edges), and the webpage has a flat background.

Comment: *Sure it makes the object stand out* sounds like reason enough for most purposes, not sure why "physycally possible" woul be better in an image, or do you mean something else within a given context?

Comment: Even if it seems physically impossible, it still tricks the eye into seeing it as a curved object. I believe it still achieves the desired look without looking "impossible" by the viewer.

Comment: That is not correct to use mathematical characters to make the title of the question bold (and stand out in the list). Please, replace them with the regular ones.

Comment: There could be lots of different reasons for implementing this style/embellishment on a UI element, one of which you have already mentioned (makes the object stand out). But since this is more to do with a styling/aesthetics choice and it can vary depending on who is implementing this, I am not sure you'll find a definitive reason for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual designers keep working on UI elements to create distinct and memorable visual elements on a website. And like you mentioned yourself, this effect brings more focus to the element.

The *curved shadow* effect is **physically possible**. The image below shows one of the ways it is possible which is if the surface isn't flat and has a slight curve with the focal point being the center of the object on the surface.

[image: Curved shadow logic]

There are other cases where this effect can be noticed:

- One being when the light is focused on the artwork in galleries.
- Another is when the paper (mostly with card sheets that come in rolls) isn't lying flat on the surface and has a natural curve towards the edges

Comment: Curved shadows are physically possible when cast onto a curved surface. Webpages are flat.

Comment: You clearly didn't read the answer

Comment: It's also possible using orthographic projection. If the paper is curved outward toward the viewer and against a flat surface, the paper will still appear rectilinear. The light source (imaginary or not) would cast a curved shadow unless it were in the same position as the viewer.